Upgrade xubuntu 20.04 to 22.04. Now I cannot activate zram
On a workstation Dell inspiron 3880 (Intel 64 bits i7-10700 CPU) after upgrading from xubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 the zram config aborts with the following error :
zramswap[9592]: modprobe: FATAL: Module zram not found in directory /lib/modules/6.8.0-45-generic.
I have re-installed zram-tools and zram-config : same error.
I know few about ubuntu so what to do now?
